# Does this linear equation system have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions

In my research I came across the following linear equations system:
$$WW^T\mathrm{diag}(V)^2x=\mathrm{diag}(V)Wy$$
Where $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, $V\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are random matrices (specifically, each entry is sampled from the standard gaussian distribution) and $y$ is arbitrary. In general, $n>>d$.

On one hand, the background leading to this system suggests it must have a solution (it follows setting the gradient of a strongly convex function to $0$). On the other, I can't seem to find a way to prove that there is a solution.

For comparison, with a "warmup" problem I got to the equation system $WW^Tx=Wy$ which is easily solvable since it just requires a solution to $W^Tx=y$, which is easy since in general $W$ is of full rank.

Comment: The LHS lies inside the range/image of $W$, but the RHS doesn't. The equation in general is not solvable.

Comment: Agreed. I think you would need either $W$ is rank-deficient or $\mathrm{diag}(V) = kI$. Both have probability zero.

Comment: I must have an error then... Thank you